# PowerShell Exclude Folders but delete contents

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script to delete all the files from a particular server, however i would like to exclude few sub-folders from deletion but delete their contents.

```
$Folder = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\Douments -Exclude *Folder1*,*Folder2*,*Folder3* -File -Recurse
Remove-item $folder -Recurse
```

Above script gives me all the contents of the folder and then i can delete all the items but this does not delete all the sub-folders

Comment: on powershell v5.1, the `-Exclude` parameter only works on _the file name_. even tho the help says `The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter` ... it only filters against the `.Name` property. you will need to get the file list, filter out the dirs that you want to keep, and then delete the files.

Comment: I am looking to delete files from the directory and sub-directory, however i want to keep few sub-directory (But delete its contents)

Comment: get a list of all the files, delete them, get a list of all the dirs, filter out the ones you want to keep, delete the remaining dirs. [*grin*]